# How to pass value from an attribute to another attribute of the same collection?

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have this extended attributes for my 'Jobs' collection:

```
   var job = _.extend(jobAttributes, {
      userId: user._id, 
      author: user.profile.name.toLowerCase(),
      submitted: new Date(),
      commentsCount: 0,
      upvoters: [],
      votes: 10,
      apply: 0,
      tweets: 0,
      views: 0,
      day1: 2,
      day2: 0
    });
```

What I'm trying to do is send the value from 'Day1' to 'Day2'

I made a 'SyncedCron' for this

```
SyncedCron.add({
name: 'Update Example',
schedule: function(parser) {
    return parser.text('every 2 minutes');
},
job: function() {
    var one = this.day1;
    Jobs.update({'day2': one});
}
});
```

But instead of updating the attribute, I got this error:

```
Error: Invalid modifier. Modifier must be an object.
```

Comment: When you are using 'this' inside the job function is probably not getting the context you want. Have you tried to just set a random value to it instead of taking it from 'this.day1'?

Comment: I modified to ' Jobs.update({_id: Jobs._id},{$set: {day2: 9, day1: 0}});' and you're right nothing happens. I just want to set a value for each 'item' inside of this collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use something like this to populate field based on another field while insert itself.
I have defined schema such as..

```
Jobs = new Mongo.Collection("jobs");

Jobs.schema = new SimpleSchema({
  day1: {
    type: SimpleSchema.Integer,
  },
  day2: {
    type: Number,
    autoValue: function() {
      if (this.isInsert) {
        return this.siblingField("day1").value;
      }
    }
  }
});

Jobs.attachSchema(Jobs.schema);
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with `Jobs.update({'day2': one});`.

From  [documentation](https://docs.meteor.com/api/collections.html#Mongo-Collection-update):

`collection.update(selector, modifier, [options], [callback])`

selector and modifier has to be provided.

Comment: Jobs.update({_id: Jobs._id},{$set: {day2: 9, day1: 0}}); no luck

Comment: hmm the syntax looks correct. No luck meaning still getting same error or?

Comment: Nothing happens. What I'm trying to do is find a way to pass "value from an attribute" to another 'attribute' of the same collection. Any idea of how can I do this?  Eg. The Data of Day 1 to Day 2